# Dynamic sprite batching

Tags: webgl, sprite, batching

i have implemented a simple 2d renderer which works but not with textures or dynamic objects.

First to say is that i have 4 `classes` that i think are the most important ones. `Renderer`, `Scene`,`Sprite`, `SpriteBatch`.

To explain what i am doing i will write a simple example.

```
var renderer = new Renderer();
var scene = new Scene();
var sprite1 = new Sprite();
scene.add(sprite1);
function render(){
    sprite1.x += 0.01;
    renderer.render(scene);
}
render();
```

And what happens inside the scene is that `new SpriteBatch` is created when first adding a `Sprite` to the scene and all further `Sprites` added to scene will be attached to the same `SpriteBatch` until the `SpriteBatch` is full.

So my Problem is that the `vertices`,

```
new Float32Array([-0.5, -0.5, 0.5, -0.5, -0.5, 0.5, -0.5, 0.5, 0.5, -0.5, 0.5, 0.5]);
```

are calculated when calling `scene.add(sprite1)`. Which makes it very different for me to animate since the `large vertexbuffer` is inside the `SpriteBatch`. So when calling `sprite1.x+= 0.01` i want to update only these `vertices` which belong to `sprite1`. However i cant see how to connect `Sprite`,`Scene` and `SpriteBatch` together to achieve a "dynamic" batching.

What are common techniques to achieve that or can you think of an method to achieve what i want?